# Global function, variable called from different files

Tags: python

I have 2 different files: 
One is from CI build:
build.py

```
ABC_ACTIVATE = False
def activate_abc():
    global ABC_ACTIVATE
    ABC_ACTIVATE = True
    # Maybe some more very long code.
```

One is from customize
customize.py

```
from build import *

activate_abc()
print ABC_ACTIVATE
```

The idea is customize the activation for each environment by 1 function instead of very long code. But it doesn't work since `ABC_ACTIVATE` is always `False`.

It seems that the global variable cannot receive the same context in the other file. Potentially some "cyclical dependencies" problem.

So my question is: Is there any better structure solution? The idea is still activate by a function and customize.py would be the last setting for apache build.

Comment: Ah sorry, I fixed it, I just wrote an simulating example.

Comment: You are seeing the value of `ABC_ACTIVATE` as it was at the moment of the import; this does not create a permanent connection between that variable in your module, and the variable in `build`..  Do `import build`, call `build.activate_abc()`, look at `build.ABC_ACTIVATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The global seem cannot receive the same context in the other files. Maybe some "cyclical dependencies" problem.

Once you imported it, `ABC_ACTIVATE` becomes local in the context of that script. Therefore, mutating the variable in `build.py` won't reflect in your other module.

> So my question is: Is there any better structure solution?

One thing you could is create an intermediary method that return the `ABC_ACTIVATE` Boolean in your `build.py`.

```
def is_abc_activated():
    return ABC_ACTIVATE
```

and then importing it like so,

```
from build import activate_abc, is_abc_activated

print(is_abc_activated())
activate_abc()
print(is_abc_activated())

>>>>
False
True
```

---

Basically, this will remove your unconditional import `from build import *` which is an anti-idiom in Python. Also, it will increase readability since accessing `ABC_ACTIVATE` can be confusing on what exactly you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion, my friend found a quite hack solution for it:

build.py:

```
ABC_ACTIVATE = False
def activate_abc(other_context):
    other_context.ABC_ACTIVATE = True
```

And in customize.py:

```
from build import *
activate_abc(sys.modules[__name__])
print ABC_ACTIVATE
```

It works now.

Answer (score -1):

That looks like incorrect syntax for a function definition in build.py: the first { should be a : and the second } is not needed as python uses indentation to signify code blocks

```
ACTIVATE = False
def activate():
    global ACTIVATE
    ACTIVATE = True
```

Maybe you could also do...

```
import build
build.activate()
```

...As when the script in build.py uses the variable in the same file whereas your imported variable is a different variable since its being imported to the current file's namespace.